# How to send POST value to API? [Swift]

Tags: swift, xcode, post, rest

I'm a Beginner at Swift. I've been looking for a solution, but I haven't found one. I'm sorry.
I have received API from server as POST to implement login during Xcode project

I think the connection was good, but the code (LoginViewController.swift) doesn't seem to go to the server. What should I do? I will attach the code

**API connection file**

```
class NetworkHandler {
    
    static let MAIN_URL = "http://localhost:8080"
    
    class func initialize () {

        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        config.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["User-Agent": "smc"]
        let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: config)
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: MAIN_URL)!)
        let dataTask = defaultSession.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("Error occur: \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
            guard let _ = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
                return
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }

class func LoginBoard(_ completeHandler: @escaping (login) -> Void) {
            let loginboard: String = MAIN_URL + "/member/login"
            guard let url = URL(string: loginboard) else {
              print("Error: cannot create URL")
                return
            }
            var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
            urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
            urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
            let session = URLSession.shared

            let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
                guard error == nil else {
                print("error calling Post on /todos/1")
                print(error!)
                    return
                }

                guard let responseData = data else {
                print("Error: did not receive data")
                    return
                }

                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder.init()
                    let LoginList = try decoder.decode(login.self, from: responseData)
                    completeHandler(LoginList)
                }
                catch {
                    print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                    return
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
```

**LoginViewController.swift**

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var LoginList: login?
    
    @IBOutlet var inputId: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var inputPass: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var alertId: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var alertPass: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        alertId.isHidden = true
        alertPass.isHidden = true

        NetworkHandler.LoginBoard() { LoginList in
        self.LoginList = LoginList
    }
}

    func loginlogic() {
        if let LoginList = self.LoginList {
            self.inputId.text = LoginList.userId
            self.inputPass.text = LoginList.userPw
            
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func btnLogin(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if inputId.text == "" {
            alertId.isHidden = false
        } else if inputId.text != "" {
            alertId.isHidden = true
        }
        
        if inputPass.text == "" {
            alertPass.isHidden = false
        } else if inputPass.text != "" {
            alertPass.isHidden = true
        }  
          loginlogic()
    }
}
```

**login json**

```
struct login: Codable {
    var userId: String?
    var userPw: String?
}
```

I've only been using the GET method until now, but it's my first time using the POST method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set body to your post request, you can use

```
urlRequest.httpBody = try! JSONEncoder().encode(loginObject)
```

Comment: API connection file > urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
next line
urlRequest.httpBody = try! JSONEncoder().encode(login) Is this how you put it?
(LoginObject = Login)

Comment: @je2 yes. did you test it?

Comment: Yes, I tested it. But [Argument type 'login.Type' does not conform to expected type 'Encodable'] There's an error.